# Java - Insert double values in DB properly

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm using H2 Database and when double and float values inserted into my H2 DB, the loss of precision is occurred and, for example, 1.7999999523162842 displayed instead of 1.8.

Comment: use rounding mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring variable type as BigDecimal instead Double or Float solved issue.